# Can I do an overwrite install of Windows 7 without losing all my apps and data?

Tags: windows-7

My local computer technician installed his store's copy of Windows 7 Premium on my computer.  I had been using Windows Vista but needed the XP component of "7".

As part of the price I paid I have a fully licensed, unopened "7" disc with all of the drivers included. The technician warned me about the "nag" screen that asks me to install my licensed copy at any time.  Without thinking I downloaded all of my usual software programs before installing the licensed copy.

Will doing this overwrite my downloads?

Answer (score 3):

Just so that I'm clear on this, the store installed a copy of windows 7, and used a product key that they had?  And now you want to switch that for the product key included with the copy of windows 7 that you bought?  That's easy.

You can change the product key without changing anything else in the installation by going to the System properties control dialog (right click on Computer and select Properties).
[image: Open System Properties]

Once open, you'll see a Change Product Key link.  Clicking that will bring up another dialog allowing you to enter the new product key.
[image]

Comment: Very good point - but note that some other software *might* have activation problems because it suddenly thinks it's on a different PC. Most software will probably be OK even if it needs activation, but a few apps out there are insanely paranoid in the number of things they check to see if maybe they're running on a different system. I've had software demand to phone home just because I resized a partition.

Comment: I'm interested to know what software did that, as I can only think of 2 classes of software that would: modern DRM'd games, most of which are already phoning home on a regular basis, and professional software, like CAD and analytical math programs.

Comment: well I've had activation issues with Adobe Creative Suite 2 and Macromedia Studio MX2004 (on Windows XP - neither runs well on Windows 7). The Adobe stuff can get particularly touchy, and it's what I was thinking of, but thinking about it more I'm not sure if it got upset by a resized partition precisely. It *did* once get upset after I restored from a backup image, probably because some kind of partition ID changed. I have to use keygens for both now anyway (I paid) - Macromedias activation stuff doesn't even exist any more, and I never allow XP online for any reason.

Comment: As for games, the most recent PC game I have is GTA San Andreas. I'd quite like to play GTA4 - for a long while I wasn't willing to upgrade my PC just for that, but now I have a better PC anyway I'm still not willing to put up with that must-be-online-for-single-player yada yada. It's a good job I still like Doom all these years later - I won't be buying any more games unless the DRM obsession dies out.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine there's some way to enter your serial # from the legit copy or 'activate' it or whatever it's called without having to reinstall.  Perhaps this link could help...

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-activate-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can update your existing Windows 7 install with the license key on your purchased 7 disc - you will need to open up the package to see the license serial number key inside.

Here is the genuine tool to do just that:
"Update your Windows product key"
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/help/genuine/product-key

This means that you won't have to re-install Windows from scratch, therefore you won't lose your files/programs or need to back them up to do this re-install.